# What is better way to assign Json Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

```
var cars = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"b":3,"c":5}];
var temp=[];
[...cars].map((item)=>{
temp.push(item)
})

temp[0]["a"]=3
console.log(cars[0]["a"]) // op->3`enter code here`
```

Why the cars array value is changing ,while changing temp array? What is better solution so that cars array doesn't change?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: ehm `temp = cars;`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems there, but the fundamental thing is that while you're creating a new *array*, you're not creating new *objects*. So both arrays contain the same objects, so when you change the state of one of those objects, you see that change regardless of which array you look in.

To make a shallow copy of an object, you can use spread notation:

```
var temp = cars.map(obj =>({...obj}));
```

That creates a new array **and** new objects in the array.

---

Separately: Don't use `map` if you're not going to use the array it returns. Someone, somewhere, is incorrectly teaching people to use `map` just to loop through things. It's not the right tool for that ([use any of these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) instead).

In your case, though, since you *did* want a new array, `map` is a good choice, just use it as above to directly create your array, rather than using just for the loop.

Comment: Awesome explanation! 

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a shallow copy of the object inside the `map()`, also you need to use the `map()` function in a right way. Map function returns a new array, so assign it to `temp`. Make a deep clone this way:

```js
var cars = [{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "b": 3,
  "c": 5
}];
var temp = [...cars].map((item) => ({ ...item }));

temp[0]["a"] = 3;
console.log("temp: ", temp[0]["a"]);
console.log("cars: ", cars[0]["a"]);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, true... Ah, I forgot to mention that in the answer. As it was in the original question, I just left it as is.

Comment: Doh! It is in the original question, isn't it? I kind of ignored that code as soon as I saw `map` without using the return value -- might as well wave a flag in front of a bull! ;-)